# Pass IDP tokens to Frontend directly from Keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, saml-2.0, keycloak-rest-api

I am using React for front-end,
Spring boot as OAuth2 resource servers in the backend and
Keycloak as my native authorization server.

Recently I started using Keycloak so I might be missing something. My requirement is that if the client configures any IDP provider ( Okta, OneLogin ) in my application and in Keycloak. Then the front end should get the IDP tokens instead of the Keycloak token and will hit my resource servers in the backend where I have configured Multi-tenancy.

In the advanced settings of the Identity Providers section, there is an option to store tokens. Upon further inspection, I found out that the tokens are getting stored as JSON in one of the tables in the Keycloak's database.

Furthermore, Keycloak has an API that will fetch the IDP tokens from that table in exchange for Keycloak tokens.
But the drawback is front end has to make an extra API call on successful IDP authentication after receiving the Keycloak token.

Basically, once the IDP authentication is successful frontend has to get the IDP tokens directly instead of getting Keycloak tokens.

I've gone through their documentation and couldn't find any viable solution to my problem. Any help is appreciated

Thanks.

[image: Reference]

[Reference-2](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#retrieving-external-idp-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing external identities in Keycloak (like the screenshot in your question suggests you are doing), you don't need multi-tenancy in your resource servers: **client(s) are issued tokens by Keycloak only**. Token from external IDPs are exchanged only between those IDPs and Keycloak (neither client(s) nor resource server(s) will ever see it).

If on the opposite your OAuth2 client(s) can get tokens directly from several IDPs (not using "login with..." on Keycloak login form), then

- Keycloak won't know about these tokens (it is exchanged between the client and the IDP without going through Keycloak)
- resource server(s) need multi-tenancy to accept tokens from all the possible issuers

The easiest solution is the 1st one, where the different identity providers are configured in Keycloak (not in your client(s)): all your client(s) and resource server(s) have to know about a single authorization server (Keycloak) and a single structure of private claims.

When a user "logs in with...", Keycloak imports the data from the ID token / userinfo endpoint in its own database. So tokens further issued by Keycloak for that user should contain the data corresponding the scopes you configured in Keycloak's `Identity providers` tab for that IDP.

##### PS

According to [latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), neither mobile apps nor Javascript based front-end running in a browser should be configured as an OAuth2 client nor have access to tokens. So, unless you are using Next.js with the OAuth2 client being in the server-side (node) part of the app, you should consider using an additional layer between your front-end and your resource server(s). For instance `spring-cloud-gateway` with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `TokenRelay` filter (which replaces session cookie with the access token in session before forwarding a request from the front-end to a resource server).

Comment: The requirement is that I want to use the IDP tokens on my Spring boot OAuth2 resource servers, to achieve this there are 2 ways

i) IDP and client ( react ) communicate directly without involving Keyclak in between.
OAuth2 Authorisation code grant_type  with PKCE will be used here. On successful authentication, the client will receive the IDP tokens

ii) IDP and Keycloak communicate directly . Even here OAuth2 authorisation code grant_type can be used with PKCE. On successful authentication Keycloak will get the IDP tokens but Keycloak tokens will be returned to the client.

Comment: Since I want the frontend to use the IDP tokens directly on my resource servers. The first approach seems feasible for me.
To add on to that, react will be using oidc-client-ts.

Comment: Open the link in my answer and read it carefully. Your React front-end should not have access to access tokens.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the link that you sent in the answer, in my current architecture I am using Nginx as a gateway to my resource servers. According to the link my architecture fits in the "Frontend-only component". As mentioned in the link, I won't be sharing any client secrets with the front-end, Instead, I will only be sending client-id, redirect-URL, and issuer-URL, this information is enough for the front-end OIDC libraries to handle the authentication.

Comment: You haven't understood it, apparently. Read the "Final Recommendation" again: **use a confidential client**. An application running in a browser can't be a confidential client. You should forget about `oidc-client-ts` or any other lib requesting tokens from a browser.

Comment: Yes, apologies for not reading the full document, my current architecture is front-end and the back-end is running on the same domain. Nginx is used as a reverse proxy and I have spring servers running which are mapped to different location blocks.
As of now, there is stateless authentication happening. I have gone through the document completely and taking all into consideration there are only 2 options for me

i) Introduce Keycloak between the front end and the Identity Provider.

ii) Backends for frontends.

Comment: I give up. You be trolling me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255182/discussion-between-akhil-and-ch4mp).